Look up all CIDR blocks for an existing VPC
When loading an existing VPC via CDK I can't load as the VPC construct or cast to the VPC construct.
Vpc.FromLookup(this, "ShardNetworkVpc", new VpcLookupOptions()); // returns IVpc

The VPC loads correctly but I need to use vpcCidrBlockAssociations which is only available on VPC.
Seems there is a bug for this but no resolution at the moment. Are there any workarounds? So I can load all existing CIDR ranges associated with my VPC?
